# How to group 2 repos in the same directory

Tags: git, merge, repository, gitlab

The project I'm working on at my job is composed of 2 main repositories `frontend` and `www`. Every time we code a new feature we often need to create a branch for each repo, push code on each repo, create commits on each repos, etc. We really hate this pattern.

Let's say we'd want a directory `project` with 2 subdirectories `frontend` and `www` and merge the two repos's .git folder at the root of the parent directory. Is it complicated?

Our goal is to end up with one single repo. This way we'd be able to type commands like `git status` inside the `project` directory and see changes for both frontend and www without having to `cd` into the other directory each time.

I know it's possible, but can't imagine a way to attempt this big change.

We don't want to lose history for both 2 repos. We have issues, PR and tags that we'd like to keep.

Hope you'll help me find an easy solution!

Comment: do you have identical files in both projects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not in any special order

#### Solution A

Copy `frontend`, without the `.git` folder into the `www` repo (and loose `frontend`'s history)

#### Solution B

Create a new fresh repo from the two old ones (just copy the folders and loose the history)

#### Solution C

[How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

**Note**: Below the accepted answer there is answer with many more upvotes.